Uploading geoip-lite to postgres
So if I want to use the geoip-lite database from maxmind and upload it to my postgres database to lookup, I'd convert the csv to json and then upload it the database or keep it as csv and upload if possible.
Do I just add an index on the main column and let query the database or is this inefficient?
I'm using Supabase. Is there an extension that makes it more performant or is an index sufficient? Or am I completely missing how to use this data?

It would be better to. have a normalized table instead of a JSON
